# wget - do not overwrite file if the download fails

Tags: wget

Imagine you download a file to `~/img.txt`

```
wget https://picsum.photos/200 -O ~/img.jpg
```

The image file is stored. Now imagine you try again but with a wrong URL

```
wget https://picsum.photooooooos/200 -O ~/img.jpg
```

The file is then erased/emptied.

How to avoid the overwriting of the file in case the URL returns 404 or there is any error with the download?

Comment: Hm, have you read `man wget`, maybe searched for "overwrite" in that, to see whether an appropriate option exists? I'm currently on my phone, but that's what I would do.

Comment: You likely want to look at `--noclobber` and and the exit status to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use a temporary file - something like this:

```bash
outFile=img.jpg

# create temporary file in /tmp and store its name in tmpFile
tmpFile=$(mktemp)

if wget https://picsum.photos/200 -O "$tmpFile"; then
   mv -f "$tmpFile" "$outFile" || echo could not replace "$outfile" >&2
else
   echo wget failed with $? >&2
fi
rm -f "$tmpFile"
```